# How to fix bug in min heap insertion / extract functions?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, minmax-heap

I compile like this:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp MinHeap.cpp -o test
```

Implementation is failing test2 "*Assertion failed: (array[i] == i), function test2, file test.cpp, line ...
Abort trap: 6*". The test2 is creating an array of size 10000 (with ints from 0 to 10000 in random order) and using heapsort and MinHeap class to sort it in order.

100% heapsort is correctly implemented. I've gone through the logic of the main MinHeap functions (insert -> bubble_up , extract -> bubble_down) but can't find the bugs.

**test.cpp**

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "MinHeap.hpp"

#include <iostream>

void heapsort(int* const array, int size){
  MinHeap heap;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    heap.insert(array[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    array[i] = heap.extractMin();
  }
}

void test2(){
  int size = 10000;
  int* array = new int[size];
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    array[i] = i;
  }

  unsigned int seed = 2019;
  std::srand(seed);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int index1 = std::rand() % size;
    int index2 = std::rand() % size;

    int number1 = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = number1;
  }

  heapsort(array, size);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    assert(array[i] == i);
  }

  delete [] array;
}

int main(){
  insert_test();
  extract_test();
  test2();
  return 0;
}
```

**MinHeap.hpp**

```cpp
#ifndef MINHEAP_HPP
#define MINHEAP_HPP

class MinHeap{
public:
  MinHeap();
  //  MinHeap(const MinHeap& other);
  //  MinHeap& operator=(const MinHeap& other);
  ~MinHeap();

  void insert(int number);
  int extractMin();
  bool isEmpty() const;
  void toString() const;

private:
  void swap(int &a, int &b);
  void expand();
  void bubble_up(int start);
  void bubble_down(int start);
  void fit();
  int find_min(int a, int b, int c);

  int* array;
  int size;
  int capacity;
};

#endif
```

**MinHeap.cpp**

```cpp
#include "MinHeap.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

MinHeap::MinHeap(){
    size = 0;
    capacity = 10000;
    array = new int[capacity];
}

MinHeap::~MinHeap(){
    delete[] array;
}

void MinHeap::insert(int number){
    if(isEmpty()){
        array[0] = number;
        size++;
        return;
    }
    if (size == capacity){
        throw std::runtime_error("Overflow, int not inserted")
    }

    array[size] = number;
    bubble_up(size);
    size++;

    return;

}

void MinHeap::swap(int &a, int &b){
    int hold = a;
    a = b;
    b = hold;
}

int MinHeap::extractMin(){
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw std::runtime_error("Not Valid");
    }
    else if (size == 1){
        size--;
        return array[0];
    }

    int min = array[0];
    array[0] = array[size-1];
    size--;
    bubble_down(0);

    return min;
}

void MinHeap::bubble_up(int start){
    int child = start;
    int parent = (child - 1)/2;

    if (start == 1){
        if (array[0] > array[1]){
            swap(array[0], array[1]);
        }
    }

    while (parent >= 0 and array[child] < array[parent]){
        swap(array[child], array[parent]);
        child = parent;
        parent = (child - 1)/2;
    }
}

void MinHeap::bubble_down(int start){
    int parent = start;
    int left = (2*parent)+1;
    int right = (2*parent)+2;

    if (left > size){
        if(array[parent] < array[right]){
                swap(array[parent], array[right]);
            }
            return;
    }
    if (right > size){
        if(array[parent] < array[left]){
                swap(array[parent], array[left]);
            }
            return;
    }

    int min = find_min(array[parent], array[left], array[right]);

    if (min == array[left]){
        swap(array[left], array[parent]);
        bubble_down(left);
    }
    else if (min == array[right]){
        swap(array[right], array[parent]);
        bubble_down(right);
    }
    return;
}

int MinHeap::find_min(int a, int b, int c){
    if (a < b and a < c){
        return a;
    }
    else if (b < a and b < c){
        return b;
    }
    return c;
}

bool MinHeap::isEmpty() const{
    if (size > 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the problematic code with a debugger to see where the program deviates from what you expect? This should help you solve the problem, and if not it will help you reduce the amount of code given to a palatable size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the last run through when the parent is 9466 in the bubble_down function, the array is going out of bounds because the limit is 10,000 and you are trying to compare the right value as being (2 * parent) + 2 which gives you 18,934. I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I think that is where the bug lies.

```
if (left > size) {
    if (array[parent] < array[right]) { // Breaking here!
        swap(array[parent], array[right]);
    }
    return;
}
```